# CUDA in-place transpose doesn't complete transpose total matrix

Tags: cuda

I've written the CUDA code below. It's supposed to transpose a matrix using tiling blocks, and the code works when using small values, but when using, for example:
TILE = 32, matrix 128 x 128, it doesn't complete the transpose, it stops after 96. In host this is my dimension thread/block

```
dim3 dimGrid((nEven + TILE_DIM - 1) / TILE_DIM, (nEven + TILE_DIM - 1) / TILE_DIM); 
dim3 dimBlock(TILE_DIM, TILE_DIM);
```

where I let the threads number == to tile block number,
the global code is simple and it should theoretically work:

```
__global__ void transposeMain( int *idata)
{
    __shared__ int tile2[TILE_DIM][TILE_DIM];

    int yyy = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM ; // col values (0,32,64,96)
    int xxx = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM ; // row values (0,32,64,96)

    if (xxx < nEven && yyy < nEven) 
    {
        tile2[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y] = idata[(threadIdx.x + xxx)*nEven + (threadIdx.y + yyy)];

        __syncthreads();

        idata[(threadIdx.y + yyy)*nEven + (threadIdx.x + xxx)] = tile2[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y];

    }
}
```

Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: hello @robertcrovella , thank you but the blog link leads to your profile is it correct ?

Comment: Sorry.  [This](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/efficient-matrix-transpose-cuda-cc/) blog.

Comment: @Robert, thanks for info , for the blog example i really never understood it, why are they using  the "+Blocks_ROW" int the for loop ? why is it 8 its value ?

Comment: It allows a single block to handle a whole tile with a reduced number of threads.  This can potentially lead to higher occupancy, which may translate to higher performance.   You don't *have* to do it this way, you can do it with a single thread per element.  Note that the blog is *not* demonstrating an in-place transpose.

Comment: A one element-per-thread method with a 32x32 tile would require 1024 threads per block.  There are many GPUs for which this block size would limit you to an occupancy of 1 threadblock per SM.  The modification with the loop, so that each thread is handling multiple elements per tile, leads to a 32x8 threadblock instead (i.e. 256 threads) which might run your occupancy up to 6 threadblocks per SM, or more, depending on GPU and other factors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to do an in-place transpose.

CUDA device code execution is broken up into threadblocks.  Threadblocks (groups of threads) can execute in any order, and do not all (typically) execute at the same time.  So when you read a tile in here:

```
tile2[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y] = idata[(threadIdx.x + xxx)*nEven + (threadIdx.y + yyy)];
```

That is OK.  But when you write the tile:

```
idata[(threadIdx.y + yyy)*nEven + (threadIdx.x + xxx)] = tile2[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y];
```

You are frequently over-writing data (in some other tile in the original matrix) which *you haven't read yet* (because the threadblock responsible for reading that tile hasn't even begun to execute yet).  Once you overwrite it like this, it's lost.

The solution (for square matrix transpose) has several aspects to it:

1. Each threadblock must first read 2 tiles. These 2 tiles from the input data will be swapped.
2. Then each threadblock can write those two tiles.
3. The tiles along the main diagonal need special casing.
4. since most threadblocks are handling 2 tiles, only threadblocks on or on one side of the main diagonal need do any work.

You haven't shown a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which is [expected](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) when you have questions like this), and your code has other issues such as the potential for uncoalesced access (lower performance) so I'm not going to try to "fix" your code.

Instead, here's a fully worked example, lifted from [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/765696/efficient-in-place-transpose-of-multiple-square-float-matrices/):

```
$ cat t469.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define uS_PER_SEC 1000000
#define uS_PER_mS 1000
#define N 4096
#define M 4096
#define TILE_DIM 32
#define BLOCK_ROWS 8



__global__ void transposeCoalesced(float *odata, const float *idata)
{
  __shared__ float tile[TILE_DIM][TILE_DIM+1];

  int x = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x;
  int y = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y;
  int width = gridDim.x * TILE_DIM;

  for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j += BLOCK_ROWS)
     tile[threadIdx.y+j][threadIdx.x] = idata[(y+j)*width + x];

  __syncthreads();

  x = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x;  // transpose block offset
  y = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y;

  for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j += BLOCK_ROWS)
     odata[(y+j)*width + x] = tile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y + j];
}

__global__ void iptransposeCoalesced(float *data)
{
  __shared__ float tile_s[TILE_DIM][TILE_DIM+1];
  __shared__ float tile_d[TILE_DIM][TILE_DIM+1];

  int x = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x;
  int y = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y;
  int width = gridDim.x * TILE_DIM;

  if (blockIdx.y>blockIdx.x) { // handle off-diagonal case
    int dx = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x;
    int dy = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y;
    for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j += BLOCK_ROWS)
      tile_s[threadIdx.y+j][threadIdx.x] = data[(y+j)*width + x];
    for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j += BLOCK_ROWS)
      tile_d[threadIdx.y+j][threadIdx.x] = data[(dy+j)*width + dx];
    __syncthreads();
    for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j += BLOCK_ROWS)
      data[(dy+j)*width + dx] = tile_s[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y + j];
    for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j += BLOCK_ROWS)
      data[(y+j)*width + x] = tile_d[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y + j];
  }

  else if (blockIdx.y==blockIdx.x){ // handle on-diagonal case
    for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j += BLOCK_ROWS)
      tile_s[threadIdx.y+j][threadIdx.x] = data[(y+j)*width + x];
    __syncthreads();
    for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j += BLOCK_ROWS)
      data[(y+j)*width + x] = tile_s[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y + j];
  }
}


int validate(const float *mat, const float *mat_t, int n, int m){
   int result = 1;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
       if (mat[(i*m)+j] != mat_t[(j*n)+i]) result = 0;
   return result;
}

int main(){

    timeval t1, t2;
    float *matrix = (float *) malloc (N * M * sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++)
      for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        matrix[(i*M) + j] = i;
// Starting the timer
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    float *matrixT = (float *) malloc (N * M * sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            matrixT[(j*N)+i] = matrix[(i*M)+j]; // matrix is obviously filled
//Ending the timer
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    if (!validate(matrix, matrixT, N, M)) {printf("fail!\n"); return 1;}
    float et1 = (((t2.tv_sec*uS_PER_SEC)+t2.tv_usec) - ((t1.tv_sec*uS_PER_SEC)+t1.tv_usec))/(float)uS_PER_mS;
    printf("CPU time = %fms\n", et1);

    float *h_matrixT , *d_matrixT , *d_matrix;
    h_matrixT = (float *) (malloc (N * M * sizeof(float)));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_matrixT , N * M * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_matrix , N * M * sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(d_matrix , matrix , N * M * sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

//Starting the timer
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

    const float alpha = 1.0;
    const float beta  = 0.0;
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    //gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    cublasCreate(&handle);
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    cublasSgeam(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N, N, M, &alpha, d_matrix, M, &beta, d_matrix, N, d_matrixT, N);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    cublasDestroy(handle);

//Ending the timer
    float et2 = (((t2.tv_sec*uS_PER_SEC)+t2.tv_usec) - ((t1.tv_sec*uS_PER_SEC)+t1.tv_usec))/(float)uS_PER_mS;
    printf("GPU Sgeam time = %fms\n", et2);

    cudaMemcpy(h_matrixT , d_matrixT , N * M * sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (!validate(matrix, h_matrixT, N, M)) {printf("fail!\n"); return 1;}
    cudaMemset(d_matrixT,0, N*M*sizeof(float));
    memset(h_matrixT, 0, N*M*sizeof(float));
    dim3 threads(TILE_DIM, BLOCK_ROWS);
    dim3 blocks(N/TILE_DIM, M/TILE_DIM);
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    transposeCoalesced<<<blocks, threads >>>(d_matrixT, d_matrix);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    cudaMemcpy(h_matrixT , d_matrixT , N * M * sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (!validate(matrix, h_matrixT, N, M)) {printf("fail!\n"); return 1;}
    float et3 = (((t2.tv_sec*uS_PER_SEC)+t2.tv_usec) - ((t1.tv_sec*uS_PER_SEC)+t1.tv_usec))/(float)uS_PER_mS;
    printf("GPU kernel time = %fms\n", et3);

    memset(h_matrixT, 0, N*M*sizeof(float));
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    iptransposeCoalesced<<<blocks, threads >>>(d_matrix);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    cudaMemcpy(h_matrixT , d_matrix , N * M * sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (!validate(matrix, h_matrixT, N, M)) {printf("fail!\n"); return 1;}
    float et4 = (((t2.tv_sec*uS_PER_SEC)+t2.tv_usec) - ((t1.tv_sec*uS_PER_SEC)+t1.tv_usec))/(float)uS_PER_mS;
    printf("GPU in-place kernel time = %fms\n", et4);


    cudaFree(d_matrix);
    cudaFree(d_matrixT);
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t469 t469.cu -lcublas
$ ./t469
CPU time = 450.095001ms
GPU Sgeam time = 1.937000ms
GPU kernel time = 1.694000ms
GPU in-place kernel time = 1.839000ms
$
```

Note that this compares several different approaches to matrix transpose.
If you study the `iptransposeCoalesced` you will see that it is adhering to the 4 specific aspects I outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

It is fishy to use `__syncthreads();` in the if statement in CUDA. Try to move it outside this block by simple:

```
if (xxx < nEven && yyy < nEven) 
{
    tile2[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y] = idata[(threadIdx.x + xxx)*nEven + (threadIdx.y + yyy)];
}
__syncthreads();
if (xxx < nEven && yyy < nEven) 
{
    idata[(threadIdx.y + yyy)*nEven + (threadIdx.x + xxx)] = tile2[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y];
}
```

Comment: hello @wojciech, thanks for reply tried but yet not worked,  its like at run there is part of row that is not transposed (in here exp block tile 32 - row/col 128/128 , so at row96 there is no transpose happens only the above)... hope its clear , do you think its related to thread number ? thank you

Comment: Not sure what cause the problem, but just wondering do you even need the syncing the threads?  In a single thread you only use the value that you have written in the same thread so no other thread from the block should be able to overwrite it. What is more - I don't even think you need the shared memory here as in this kind of situation you are free to use registers.

Comment: hello @wojciech , thanks for reply , i first used the synch becoz i felt when not using it the values went disrupting in other locations, also used the shared as was told its much better than the registers in space, so removed the shared and used register ( its normal initialize for array right ? like int array[x][y] and removing the shared ,? ) but when using other sizes matrices , it partly doesn't work, like example Tile = 16, matrix size 128 x 128 , and i need to even make the tile up to 32 with matrix size 1024 minimum,... i really need  help into finding what went wrong, many thanks

Comment: I rather think on using a single register rather than array. In line:
`tile2[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y] = idata[(threadIdx.x + xxx)*nEven + (threadIdx.y + yyy)];` 
You write in the same place as you are reading from in the line:
`idata[(threadIdx.y + yyy)*nEven + (threadIdx.x + xxx)] = tile2[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y];` Kernel can be perceived as the function that is performed in a single thread for threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y, blockIdx.x, blockIdx.y and as so you can:
`int v = idata[(threadIdx.x + xxx)*nEven + (threadIdx.y + yyy)];` 
`idata[(threadIdx.y + yyy)*nEven + (threadIdx.x + xxx)] = v`.